# Runing map reduce job by unix

Tags: unix, hadoop

I need to run bellow map reduce command from unix shell script.

```
MR_COMMAND="StreamsOnly_RM.jar -conf StreamsOnly_RM.xml \"$input_dir1/*/$IPPattern1\" $temp_output $output_dir"
```

a echo command results the following.

```
echo "hadoop jar $MR_COMMAND"

hadoop jar StreamsOnly_RM.jar -conf StreamsOnly_RM.xml "Streams0//{20130518,20130517}/*/part*" /temp/ /output
```

When i fire this command this is working fine but in unix script

```
hadoop jar $MR_COMMAND
```

gives exception java.uri.net exception invalid path exception for Streams0//20130518/*/part*%22

Comment: What is "Streams0" in your path, is it supposed to be a directory? If a file is in HDFS you should prefix with hdfs://

Comment: i have ignored hdfs:// for simplicity ..it is there

Comment: Can you post the full exception trace (if there is one)